# React eslint error missing in props validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, flowtype

I have the next code, eslint throw:

> react/prop-types onClickOut; is missing in props validation
>
> react/prop-types children; is missing in props validation

`propTypes` was defined but eslint does not recognize it.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class IxClickOut extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any,
    onClickOut: PropTypes.func,
  };

 componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById('app')
      .addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.getElementById('app')
      .removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
  }

  handleClick = ({ target }: { target: EventTarget }) => {
    if (!this.containerRef.contains(target)) {
      this.props.onClickOut();
    }
  };

  containerRef: HTMLElement;

  render() {
    const { children, ...rest } = this.props;
    const filteredProps = _.omit(rest, 'onClickOut');

    return (
      <div
        {...filteredProps}
        ref={container => {
          this.containerRef = container;
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default IxClickOut;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "verinmueblesmeteor",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "ios": "NODE_ENV=developement meteor run ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fine-uploader": "^5.10.1",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.2.3",
    "install": "^0.8.1",
    "ix-gm-polygon": "^1.0.11",
    "ix-type-building": "^1.4.4",
    "ix-type-offer": "^1.0.10",
    "ix-utils": "^1.3.7",
    "keymirror": "^0.1.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "npm": "^3.10.3",
    "rc-slider": "^3.7.3",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-fileupload": "^2.2.0",
    "react-list": "^0.7.18",
    "react-modal": "^1.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.6.0",
    "react-styleable": "^2.2.4",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^4.0.4",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-form": "^5.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.9",
    "rxjs-es": "^5.0.0-beta.9",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.0.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.7.1",
    "eslint": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-meteor": "^0.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.8.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^2.6.0",
    "sasslets-animate": "0.0.4"
  },
  "cssModules": {
    "ignorePaths": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "jsClassNamingConvention": {
      "camelCase": true
    },
    "extensions": [
      "scss",
      "sass"
    ],
    "postcssPlugins": {
      "postcss-modules-values": {},
      "postcss-modules-local-by-default": {},
      "postcss-modules-extract-imports": {},
      "postcss-modules-scope": {},
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "whitelist": [
      "es7.decorators",
      "es7.classProperties",
      "es7.exportExtensions",
      "es7.comprehensions",
      "es6.modules"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "no-underscore-dangle": ["error", { "allow": [_id, b_codes_id] }],
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": "meteor"
  },
  "globals": {
    "_": true,
    "CSSModule": true,
    "Streamy": true,
    "ReactClass": true,
    "SyntheticKeyboardEvent": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps best to write:
`const { children, onClickOut, ...filteredProps } = this.props;`

Comment: Are you using babel-eslint?

Comment: @horyd not, if i do it eslint throw
no-unused-vars onClickOut is defined but never used

Comment: try to define it as: `static get propTypes() { return { children: PropTypes.any,
    onClickOut: PropTypes.func }; }`

Comment: yes @TimoSta i use babel-eslint

Comment: I came here looking for a way to reduce this eslint rule to a warning, not an error. In case you're like me, you can add this entry to your `rules` object in your eslint config: `"react/prop-types": 1`

Comment: in my case adding `import React from "react";` worked (no idea why it wasn't there in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in flow annotation in handleClick, i removed this and works fine
thanks @alik

Answer (score 170):

I know this answer is ridiculous, but consider just disabling this rule until the bugs are worked out or you've upgraded your tooling:

```js
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */ // TODO: upgrade to latest eslint tooling
```

Or disable project-wide in your eslintrc:

```json
"rules": {
  "react/prop-types": "off"
}
```

Comment: The actual syntax for disabling this rule is: "react/prop-types": "off"

Comment: Thanks this is also what I used in eslintrc under the rules section

Comment: IMO, this is a bad practice and shouldn't be recommended to developers. Disabling rules can lead you down rabbit holes of writing poor code. (i.e. disabling rules whenever it seems more convenient.)

Comment: It might be helpful for cases when the main config is setup for JS files, and, in addition, there is an override for .ts/tsx files based on TS parser for ESLint. Hence, it seems a good thing to turn off PropTypes within the override section for TS. At the same time, main part of ESLint config should still verify PropTypes for JS files.

Answer (score 135):

You need to define `propTypes` as a static getter if you want it inside the class declaration:

```
static get propTypes() { 
    return { 
        children: PropTypes.any, 
        onClickOut: PropTypes.func 
    }; 
}
```

If you want to define it as an object, you need to define it outside the class, like this:

```
IxClickOut.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any,
    onClickOut: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Also it's better if you import prop types from `prop-types`, **not** `react`, otherwise you'll see warnings in console (as preparation for [React 16](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/nuka-carousel/issues/212)):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Comment: Depends on the Babel config, it doesn't need to be a better if you're using the static properties plugin.

Comment: Thanks.
The first option throw the same error, the second option solve the problem but i dont understend why defining as class attribute throws an error in this case.
Note: I have another components that work fine defining as class attribute

Comment: Not sure why one fails and the other one works. I thought it needed to be defined statically on a class either way, perhaps I was wrong.

Answer (score 22):

I ran into this issue over the past couple days. Like Omri Aharon said in their answer above, it is important to add definitions for your prop types similar to:

```
SomeClass.propTypes = {
    someProp: PropTypes.number,
    onTap: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Don't forget to add the prop definitions outside of your class. I would place it right below/above my class. If you are not sure what your variable type or suffix is for your PropType (ex: PropTypes.number), refer to this [npm reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types). To Use PropTypes, you must import the package:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

If you get the linting error:`someProp is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration` all you have to do is either add `.isRequired` to the end of your prop definition like so:

```
SomeClass.propTypes = {
    someProp: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    onTap: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

**OR add default prop values like so:**

```
SomeClass.defaultProps = {
    someProp: 1
};
```

If you are anything like me, unexperienced or unfamiliar with reactjs, you may also get this error: `Must use destructuring props assignment`. To fix this error, define your props before they are used. For example:

```
const { someProp } = this.props;
```

Answer (score 21):

It seems that the problem is in [`eslint-plugin-react`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react).

It can not correctly detect what props were mentioned in `propTypes` if you have annotated named objects via destructuring anywhere in the class.

There was [similar problem](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/498) in the past

Comment: I am using babel-eslint and enable all stages
Note: I have another components that work fine defining as class attribute

Comment: @cristiancamilocedeñogallego post relevant configs: `package.json`, `.eslintrc` It is hard to tell why it doesn't pick up propTypes

Comment: so the problem is in flow annotation in `handleClick`

Comment: yes @alik was remove the flow annotation and works fine

Answer (score 14):

Install prop-types package with- `npm i prop-types --save`
Import it-

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Then specify the props, I implemented this way-

```
Text.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default function Text({ children }) {
  return (
    <VStyle className="para">
      <p>{children}</p>
    </VStyle> 
  );
}
```

Also add this in your eslintrc.json or .js file

```
"rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

On the new version of React and also Next.js, you can simply import PropTypes as follows,

`import PropTypes from "prop-types";`

and at the bottom of your file add defaultProps and propTypes such as,

```
Post.defaultProps = {
  posts: "",
};

Post.propTypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Post;
```

It should resolve your eslint warnings.

Answer (score 4):

Issue:  'id1' is missing in props validation, eslintreact/prop-types

```
<div id={props.id1} >
    ...
</div>
```

Below solution worked, in a function component:

```
let { id1 } = props;

<div id={id1} >
    ...
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

For me, upgrading **eslint-plugin-react** to the latest version 7.21.5 fixed this

Answer (score 4):

PropTypes checking is a good thing, not recommend to ignore by settings

You can auto generate the propTypes by using vscode React PropTypes Generate extension:

1. Select your Component's name
2. Press command + . (Windows is Ctrl + .) show Code Actions and select PropTypesGenerate, or press shift + command + alt + P (Windows is shift + ctrl + alt + P) in the macOS
3. Input propType to replace default type

Answer (score 4):

Another way is:

---

File: App.js

```
    ...
        <Component1 key1="abc" />
    ...
```

---

File: Component1.js

1 **error**:

```
    function Component1 ({ key1 }) {
        console.log('key1', key1);
    }
```

2 **error**:

```
    function Component1 (props) {
        let{ key1 } = props;
        console.log('key1', key1);
    }
```

3 **works**:

NOTE: `prop` instead of `props`

```
    function Component1 (prop) {
        let{ key1 } = prop;
        console.log('key1', key1);
    }
```

Looks like, linter only checks for proper word `props`, not for `prop` or like.
It's a solution if you are just getting started or quick prototyping.
For later or large projects, defining proptypes might be better.

---

Answer (score 3):

If you want to solve this problem in the right way without having to disable the rule, then you can do this: (let's call the flagged prop: 'prop')

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  // Your component code here
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  prop: PropTypes.string, 
  // Other prop validations can continue from here
};
```

Note: I am suggesting this example using React-vite set-up

Comment: If you're using vite and jsx. This is an important solution

Comment: This worked for me. I am also using vite setup.

Answer (score 2):

I'm finding eslint to be overly strict in the project I'm working on myself but for this error I fixed it by defining my interface and then implementing as such:

```
interface myInterface: {
  test: string
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<myInterface> = (props: myInterface) => {
```

Answer (score 2):

Duplicating my answer from a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69199304/4290193

`eslint-plugin-react@^7.25.0` appears to have [resolved](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/pull/3051) the issue for those using `React.FC<IProps>` with `react/prop-types` validation rule.

So instead of

```
const Example: React.FC<IProps> = (props: IProps) => ...
```

This now works without warnings after the update

```
const Example: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is facing this issue with a function component here is the correct way to eliminate the TS error, without disabling the lint check.

```
Props = {testId: string}

const ComponentWithChildren: FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = (props: PropsWithChildren<Props>) => (
    <>{props.children}</>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional React component. Defined as object. I got this error because I copied and pasted the object from a different with a slightly different name and forgot to change the name of the proptypes object.

```
FooterIcons.propTypes = {} -> FooterIcon.propTypes
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disable `prop-types` rule, we can introduce children property as part of component props, eg:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ErrorBoundary extends Component<{ children: React.ReactNode }> {
  constructor(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error: Readonly<unknown>, errorInfo: Readonly<unknown>): void {
    this.setState({ error, errorInfo });
  }

  render(): React.ReactElement | React.ReactNode {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { error, errorInfo } = this.state as Readonly<Record<string, { componentStack: string }>>;

    if (errorInfo)
      return (
        <details>
          <h3>Oops, error detected.</h3>
          <p>{error?.toString()}</p>
          <p>{errorInfo?.componentStack}</p>
        </details>
      );
    return children;
  }
}
```

Above one is typical example of getting `eslint` error gone ~~

Don't worry be happy ~~

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem in `React JS:18.2.0`. After configuring `.eslintrc.cjs`  the problem is solved. Configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
  parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: 'latest', sourceType: 'module' },
  settings: { react: { version: '18.2' } },
  plugins: ['react-refresh'],
  rules: {
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react-refresh/only-export-components": [
      "warn",
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 2,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error",
  },
}
```

Comment: Aren't you turning off the props checking here? 
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else encountering this issue when using Javascript (as opposed to TypeScript), `React-Admin`'s linter was bombing out on the following:

```js
const MyCustomRow = ({
    record,
    id
}) => {
    // code here
    ...
```

Even though my IDE's custom linter wasn't happy with the mix-and-match, it made the `react` linter happy and had no adverse effects:

```js
const MyCustomRow = ({
    record,
    id
}: {
    record: Record<string, unknown>,
    id: string
}) => {
    // code here
    ...
```

*EDIT: I guess I could have used `DatagridRowProps` (see the `body` example [in the React-Admin docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Datagrid.html), that might be the better approach)*

The alternative was disabling the `eslint` rule by adding the following directive to the top of the file:

```js
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a real life example with a solution. Put this code inside a function with the problems, update the props names and data types (int, string etc...) according to your code:

```
    funcname.propTypes = {
    propName1: PropTypes.any,
    propName2: PropTypes.any,
    propName3: PropTypes.any,
  };
```

Code above will fix the problem under with the {props.style}, {props.question} and {props.answer} in the FAQ arrow function.

```
    const FAQ = (props) => {
        FAQ.propTypes = {
          style: PropTypes.string,
          question: PropTypes.string,
          answer: PropTypes.string,
        };

        let [show, setShow] = useState(true);
        return (
          <>
            {/* FAQ questions and answers script */}
    
            <div className={`mx-[5vw] border border-gray 
             ${props.style}`}>
              <div
                onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
                className="flex justify-between text-gray duration-500 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray hover:fill-white hover:text-white"
              >
                <p className="m-4 w-full font-inter text-lg font-extrabold">
                  {props.question}
                </p>
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    height="40"
                    viewBox="0 -960 960 960"
                    width="40"
                  >
                    <path
                      d={
                        show
                          ? "M480-344 240-584l56-56 184 184 184-184 56 56-240 240Z"
                          : "M480-528 296-344l-56-56 240-240 240 240-56 56-184-184Z"
                      }
                    />
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div
                className={`font-interm p-6 md:text-lg ${show ? "hidden" : "flex"}`}
              >
                {props.answer}
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the react/prop-types ESLint rule

Open Your file: .eslintrc.cjs

and add`enter code here`

rules: {
"react-refresh/only-export-components": [
"warn",
{ allowConstantExport: true, "react/prop-types": "off" },
],

Answer (score 0):

**Go to .eslintrc.js file add this line inside rules object**

```
"react/prop-types": "off",
```

.eslintrc.cjs:

[image: .eslintrc.cjs]

Comment: Add more context to the message. Avoid using external images as they can be removed in the future. You can attach your code directly if need be. Still, if you want to use images, give it a proper name