# 'columnLinks' is missing in props validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have looked up this issue and so far is seems that most of these error are caused by typos, but I'm pretty sure I don't have one. With this code:

```js
const Component = (props: Props): ReactElement => {
  const createColumnData = (): ColumnProps<TableDataPoint>[] => Object.keys(
    props.dataSource[0],
  )
    .map((key, _, arr) => ({
      title: key.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, (str) => str.toUpperCase()),
      dataIndex: key,
      width: `${100 / Math.floor(arr.length)}%`,
      render: props.columnLinks[key]
        ? ((text): ReactElement => <a href={props.columnLinks[key]}>{text}</a>) // error is in columnLinks here
        : undefined,
    }));
```

I get the error `'columnLinks' is missing in props validation` and I'm not sure why. Has it got to do with passing JS in to an href?

Also I am aware that there is no point in using a ternary operator with one branch returning undefined, but TypeScript is throwing an error when I use `&&` in this situation.

Comment: it sounds like that is a linter error and not a react/typescript error, in that case, even though it is annoying it has no bearing on the outcome of the code and might just be some pedantic configuration

Comment: Confirmed linting error from github: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2353

Comment: Ah awesome thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find out why it's happening, or are you after a solution? As you said, you don't need the ternary; Regardless, it [seems to be a linting error](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2353) with TypeScript's handling of inferred typing on arrow functions.

If you need the error to go away while preserving the ternary, you could specifically type `columnLinks` instead of letting TS infer it, or change the arrow function out. Depending on how the component is written outside of this block, you might find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38684925/7447383) useful for defining `propTypes`!

Alternatively, why not just be rid of the ternary if you know that you don't need it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - `columnLinks` prop is passed down in an object that uses this interface: `[key: string]: string;` so I have typed the object that is passed as a prop. Changing the Arrow function out doesn't seem to to fix the issue for me.