# Object Destructuring eslint throws react/prop-types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

```
export const Top = (props) => {

    return (
        <div key={props.id} className={props.borderColor}>
            <div className="h-3/4 bg-green-200 border-black border-1 grid justify-items-center">
                <p className="text-xl font-bold">{props.title}</p>
...
```

My code looked so until I read the Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide.

Then I changed it to the following.

```
export const Top = (props) => {
    const { id, borderColor, title, price, color } = props;
    
    return (
        <div key={id} className={borderColor}>
            <div className="h-3/4 bg-green-200 border-black border-1 grid justify-items-center">
                <p className="text-xl font-bold">{title}</p>
```

I liked it, but eslint accused me of the following error:

```
'id' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
```

After a short research I came across the following
[React eslint error missing in props validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684925/react-eslint-error-missing-in-props-validation)

So I have changed my code.

```
export const Top = () => {
    const { id, borderColor, title, price, color } = this.props;

    return (
        <div key={id} className={borderColor}>
            <div className="h-3/4 bg-green-200 border-black border-1 grid justify-items-center">
                <p className="text-xl font-bold">{title}</p>
```

The error went away, but then i got this error:

```
Stateless functional components should not use `this`  react/no-this-in-sfc
```

Probably not a good solution and I don't use classes.

The Airbnb Guidlines say the following is the best way to go.

```
function getFullName({ firstName, lastName }) {
  return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}
```

But what if you have more than 2 parameters in the parentheses? I remember this being talked about as bad in the clean code book by robert c martin.

What works well for you? I also don't want to disable any rules, but would like to solve the problem in a clean way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const Top = (props) => {
const { id, borderColor, title, price, color } = props;

return (
    <div key={id} className={borderColor}>
        <div className="h-3/4 bg-green-200 border-black border-1 grid justify-items-center">
            <p className="text-xl font-bold">{title}</p>
```

This was right. Just you have to do some extra code.

- Before export block you have to import `PropTypes`

  ```
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  ```
- Then after export block you have to add these

  ```
  Top.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.oneOfType(PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string),
    borderColor: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    price: PropTypes.number,
    color: PropTypes.string,
  }
  ```

For more details, checkout this link https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please mark this answer as accepted? Otherwise, in the future, when somebody will see this question, s(he) can get confused about whether the answer is working or not. @Jens

Answer (score 0):

you got the second error (with `this`) becuase there is no `this` in function component

try:

```
export const Top = (props) => {
    const { id, borderColor, title, price, color } = props;
...
```

you can get the component's props using this methods 
1)

```
export default MyComponent(props){
...
}
```

2. destructure the props object

```
export default MyComponent({prop1, prop2, prop3} ...){
...
}
```

i don't like the the second option because if tomorrow you will add 10 new props you need to make sure you added this to the parentheses and after that the parentheses will look much much longer then before which makes it unreadable

but if it is a small component the second option is the best