# React error - "is missing in props validation"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, destructuring

it is the first time I got this error, I never had this error back in my previous react-app project which I did two months ago

The error says that:
**'column.title' is missing props validation**
**'column' is missing props validation"**
column is props from parent element, I used destructuring to that props.column

I used **eslint** that tells me this type of error... just for additional info

this is the **App.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import Column from './Column';
import { initialData } from './initial-data';

const App = () => {
  const [Data] = React.useState(initialData);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(Data);
  }, [Data]);

  return Data.columnOrder.map((dataId) => {
    const { tasks, columns } = Data;
    const column = columns[dataId];
    const tasksData = column.taskIds.map((taskId) => tasks[taskId]);

    return <Column key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasksData}></Column>;
  });
};

export default App;
```

this is **Column.js**: ---> which I got the error from

```
import React from 'react';
// import styled from 'styled-components';

// const Container = styled.div``;
// const Title = styled.h3``;
// const TaskList = styled.div``;

const Column = (props) => {
  const { title } = props.column;  --> 'error is in this line'

  return <p> {title} </p>;
};

export default Column;
```

Comment: you probably have a rule that requires propTypes

Comment: please put rule that mentions propTypes also

Comment: See it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684925/react-eslint-error-missing-in-props-validation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, problem is eslint wants to you use [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

You need to add after `Column` component something like this (but with your props properties):

```
Column.propTypes = {
    column: PropTypes.shape({
        title: PropTypes.string
    })
};
```

Also, don't forget install [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types).

Comment: thank you @Anton Neverov for the solution. It works for me

Comment: I never install prop-types, I think that it is already included in react library