# React adds array when using props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that passes an array of movies to a child component:

```
const movies: IMovie[] = data.movies;
console.log(movies);

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <DashboardMovieOverviewMenu />
    { movies.length > 0 ? <MovieOverview movies={movies} /> : null }
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

The child component:

```
const MovieOverview = (props) => {
  const movies = props;
  console.log(movies);
  ...
}
```

The movies object in the child component has an array of movies, it's not an array itself:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the `movies` like so:

```
const movies = props;
```

This will set **all the props** to the `movies` `const`

---

Since `props` is object, I guess you ment:

```
const movies = props.movies;
```

---

Or use [object destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like so:

```
const { movies = [] } = props;
```

Comment: I can't use any objects in props: `'movies' is missing in props validation eslintreact/prop-types`. Same goes for the object destruction. Okay I got it.

Comment: That error indicates you forgot to add the `movies` prop to the declaration. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684925/react-eslint-error-missing-in-props-validation) for more details. Using an array as prop is very basic stuff and should work fine ;) Success!

Answer (score 0):

It should be de-structured like the following

```
const MovieOverview = (props) => {
  const { movies } = props;
  console.log(movies);
  ...
}
```

OR you can de-structure in the args

```
const MovieOverview = ({ movies }) => {
  console.log(movies);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In child component you will not recieve the data type directly either array or any other format.
Each data from parent has to be passed to child with some meaningful name(called props).

while recieving in child component you have to use `props.variablename`.

In your case you passed movies list with movies variable name.
ex: `<MovieOverview movies={movies} />`

on the other hand whild recieving in child you have to use props.movies to read the movies list array.
ex: `const movies = props.movies;`