# 'setLoading' is missing in props validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using react 17.0.2 with Typescript. I'm trying to pass `setLoading` from the parent component (`App`) to the child component (`About`) such that the loading state in `App` can be set from `About`.

```
interface AboutProps {
  setLoading: (arg: boolean | undefined) => void
}

const About: React.FC<AboutProps> = ({ setLoading }) => {
  const fields = [
       ...
  ];

  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch('About', fields);

  useEffect(() => setLoading(loading), [loading]);

  return (
    <div className="aboutComponent">
        <div>
          <Title title={data.custom_title} />
          <Card
            text={data.body}
          >
            <Skills
              skills_={data.skills}
              skillYears_={data.skill_years}
              columns_={data.n_skills_columns}
            />
          </Card>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

However, ESLint is complaining about missing props validation for `setLoading` in line 1. The `setLoading` function is passed from the parent component here:

```
const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<any>(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <About setLoading={setLoading} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I haven't seen this error before and I'm not sure what to do, since I already type the props with `AboutProps` interface.

Comment: Do you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684925/react-eslint-error-missing-in-props-validation)

Comment: I did, but I wasn't sure which type belongs to the `setLoading` prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to TypeScript as well, but I believe you can do this:

```
const About = ({ setLoading }:AboutProps) => {
```

Also, [React TypeScript Cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components) has a section about React.FC being discouraged.