# 'children' is missing in props validation react/prop-types

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I know this has been asked a few times but the current answers do not help me.

I am using `auth0` to do some authentication work. I just intalled `esLint` and suddenly I am getting linting issues that I am unfamiliar with.

Right now this code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react'

const isAuthenticated = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0()
  return isAuthenticated
}

export function IfAuthenticated({ children }) {
  return isAuthenticated() ? <>{children}</> : null
}

export function IfNotAuthenticated({ children }) {
  return !isAuthenticated() ? <>{children}</> : null
}
```

Is getting this error:

```
src/components/Authenticated.jsx
  Line 9:35:   'children' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  Line 14:38:  'children' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

I tried to import `PropTypes` but that doesn't seem to help (not sure if I was doing it right.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you create sandbox link to replicate that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the **propTypes** in function. Please check more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684925/react-eslint-error-missing-in-props-validation)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export function IfAuthenticated({ children }) {
  IfAuthenticated.propTypes = {
      children: PropTypes.any
  };

  return isAuthenticated() ? <>{children}</> : null
}

export function IfNotAuthenticated({ children }) {
  IfNotAuthenticated.propTypes = {
      children: PropTypes.any
  };

  return !isAuthenticated() ? <>{children}</> : null
}
```

Comment: thank you this worked - however I don't fully understand what PropTypes are - and the linked response doesn't make it clearer for me (I am new).

Comment: This article was helpful for me to understand what PropTypes are. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-proptypes/