# how i can fix this problem 'onSubmit' is missing in props validation?

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuH0T.png)

i am creating react app with vite .

to fix the problem  i'm trying (npm install prop-types)then (import PropTypes from 'prop-types';) but dosen't work ,
and
the code work fine in chrome console without any problem

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing in props validation (props-types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73798187/missing-in-props-validation-props-types)

Answer (score 2):

You should add the prop types validation after the component.

```
Form.propTypes = {
    onSubmit: PropTypes.<your type>
}
```