# a to-do with react + vite, with pnpm

Tags: reactjs, eslint, vite, pnpm

I need to send the 'newTask' but the eslint is saying there is an error, and I do not why. It says "onSubmit is missing in props validation". Could you help me?

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import '../stylesheets/TaskForm.css'
import uuid from 'react-uuid'

function TaskForm(props) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  const handleChanging = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSending = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    const newTask = {
      id: uuid(),
      text: input,
      done: false
    }

    props.onSubmit(newTask)
  }

  return (
    <form
      className='task-form'
      onSubmit={handleSending}>
      <input
        className='task-input'
        type='text'
        placeholder='Make a new to-do ...'
        name='text'
        onChange={handleChanging}
      />
      <button className='task-button'>
        Add task
      </button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default TaskForm
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React eslint error missing in props validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684925/react-eslint-error-missing-in-props-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property "Type='submit'" for the button

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).